# Linker and LayoutInflater.Inflate(int, Android.Views.ViewGroup)

Tags: linker, xamarin.android

i use Mvx.MvxFrameControl successfully with most views. One of these views uses a custom control built from scratch. In release mode only, while inflating this view, the app crashes.

The log shows that a method has been optimized away and is missing.

```
at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.wrapper_native_...
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[])
at Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate(int, Android.Views.ViewGroup)
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContext.CommonInflate(int,Android.View.ViewGroup, IMvxLayoutInfactorFactory)
....
```

So i tried to add these lines to the MainApp constructor in the MainApp class.

```
public class MainApp : Application
{
    public MainApp(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
        //For linker only
        Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        if(inflater != null)
            inflater.Inflate(0, null);
    }
```

I was hoping the linker would not optimize the method away. But no luck. The method is still missing. How to fix this ?

EDIT: I've tryed Cheesebaron.HorizontalListView.Demo project in release mode in the Android 4.3 simulator and it aslo crashes.

EDIT: it seems the linking problem is related to all classes deriving from `AdatperView<T>`

EDIT: more stacktrace

```
01-03 03:20:46.185 E/mono-rt ( 2106): Stacktrace:
01-03 03:20:46.185 E/mono-rt ( 2106): 
01-03 03:20:46.195 E/mono-rt ( 2106):   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
01-03 03:20:46.195 E/mono-rt ( 2106):   at (wrapper managed-to-native)    object.wrapper_native_0xb6360af0 (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <0xffffffff>
01-03 03:20:46.195 E/mono-rt ( 2106):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod     (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <0x00068>
01-03 03:20:46.195 E/mono-rt ( 2106):   at Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate (int,Android.Views.ViewGroup) <0x00147>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [a bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17014). The workaround is to provide a [custom linker script](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#Custom_Linking) by adding a new file to your project with a **Build action** of `LinkDescription` and the file contents:

```xml
<linker>
  <assembly fullname="Mono.Android">
    <type fullname="Android.Widget.AdapterView">
      <method name="GetGetAdapterHandler" />
      <method name="GetSetAdapter_Landroid_widget_Adapter_Handler" />
    </type>
  </assembly>
</linker>
```

Comment: I tryed solutions based on LinkDescription files in this past year and they never worked. I took hours with them. I probably missed somethings... The doc probably should have a demo solution, with one project without the LinkDescription file showing the crash, and another with the LinkDescription file showing that it works.